# Can we run two LOGIN MODULES ? If not, please help me

Tags: php, joomla

My website is having 2 Login Clubs, viz., Userclub and Guestclub. I have activated the login module and in mod_userlogin/tmpl.php, I have edited the code such that login goes to userclub..but how can i create another module for the guest login ??,

My code :

```
    function val()
{
if(document.userLogin.LoginName.value=='')
{
document.userLogin.LoginName.focus();
alert('Please enter username');
return false;
}
if(document.userLogin.Password.value=='')
{
document.userLogin.Password.focus();
alert('Please enter password');
return false;
}
}

<?php // no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die('Restricted access'); ?>
<div id="outerdiv">
<div id="innerdiv">
<form name="userLogin" method="post" action="http://******/UserClub/jsp/checkprevilege.jsp" onSubmit="return val()">
```

Its not the full code, but vital part is pasted here, I am thinking to put another login via Components !, Is it possible, Please reply me........

Thanks a lot ...

Comment: Sounds like a really bad idea. One of the main complaints of users is having to log in on every other website they visit. So having two login options on a single page is not very user friendly.

Comment: @Jacco No sir, not on a single page, I have provided two links on mainmenu so that user can click on either guest/ user clubs respectivley, I dont thnk its bad idea !! what say!?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I meant so write 'single website'. Usability studies have shown that 'having to log in on every other website' is in the top list of online annoyances. But, there is no arguing against opinions, so good luck with your website :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try two modules with one redirecting to your Guest page, and one redirecting to your Userclub. Control the access levels of the users granting access / denying access?

Comment: Is that can be possible ?, because as considering joomla framework as a whole, can we redirect to different login modules ?? Can u please elaborate your reply against this doubt ?? 

Thankz Mac

Comment: You wanted to redirect to Page Y with Module 1 and Page X with Module 2. You should control access levels of Page Y and Page X with user access levels :) - Check your Login Module Parameters.